# Jquery Submit function does not send post data

Tags: jquery, forms

Appreciate any guidance on this one as I can't find the proper documentation to fix it.

I have a basic form that sends some data to a php page for processing. I've recently installed a Jquery script to prevent the submit button from being pressed more than once. From what I can tell, the Submit() function isn't passing Post data to the next PHP page for processing, and not sure what I'm missing.

Here is the form:

```
    <form class="form-inline" style="display: inline-block;" action="XXX.php" method="post">
    <input name="Country" type="hidden" value="USA"/>
    <input name="Subject" type="hidden" value="Item1"/>
    <input name="Record_ID" type="hidden" value="1"/>
    <button name="App" type="submit" value="New" class="btn btn-primary">Send Request</button>
    </form>
```

Here is the Script:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('form').submit(function() {
            //disable the submit button and update text
            $(this).children('button').attr("disabled", true);
            $(this).children('button').text('Please Wait...');
            return true;
        });
    });
    </script>
```

When I click the "Send Request" button, the text changes, and the form submits, but the post data doesn't seem to come along for the ride. I've seen references to things like serialize, but can't figure out how to make it work since I'm not using Ajax. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Serialize is only for ajax, which as you said you are not doing.  Question, if you comment out you're entire js block and let the form submit without it, does it send the data?  Also you said it seems like the data isn't sent.  How are you verifying that?

Comment: Thanks. Without the jquery, the form submits fine. Really the only thing I was trying to do was to limit the button to a single click as the process on the next page can take a solid second to execute and I had users clicking the button multiple times.

Comment: It's also probably worth mentioning that there are multiple forms on this page with the submission. I'm leaning towards a hypothesis that my selector is wrong and that's what's causing it...just can't get my brain wrapped around it.

Comment: I wouldn't think disabling the submit button would do anything to the submit after it has triggered, but maybe it is.  Try this instead and see if it still submits and stops your multiple submitting issue.  https://jsfiddle.net/v1txu7oy/

Comment: So your code does work, but if I try to disable the button and change its text, it breaks it again. Any suggestions for how to work the changes of the button into that existing fiddle?

Comment: Don't disable the button.  Just update the text.  If you use that fiddle I shared, it will prevent the submits.  They can still click the button, but it will do nothing.   https://jsfiddle.net/v1txu7oy/1/

Comment: Thanks. Wish I could figure out why it's not working if I disable the button, but changing the text works, and I have confirmed that multiple submissions no longer occur. I'm going to post the working code above for reference of others in the future. There is definitely something wrong with the way I use Jquery selectors though...

Comment: From your snipplet your selectors look fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

****Here's what actually ended up working, though I am unable to disable the button as it breaks the form if I try to do it. I can tell that I haven't been using the jquery selectors correctly as before I was attempting $(this).child('button') which wouldn't select the button properly. The version below works, however if I attempt to add this line:

```
$("button", this).attr('disabled', true);
```

Then the form won't submit. So the code below does work (Thanks @Taplar), and I have confirmed that it only allows the form to be submitted once... the user can just sit there and click it a hundred times if they want, but nothing happens after the first click.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var formsEnabled = true;

      $('form').submit(function(e) {
        if (!formsEnabled) e.preventDefault();
        $("button", this).text('Please Wait...');

        formsEnabled = false;
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't tested but how about:

`$(this).css("pointer-events:none");`

This should disable click of the button without disabling the POST data.